# Did Imgur discontinue its image feed for specific Subreddits two days ago?

Tags: images, feeds, reddit, imgur

With `https://imgur.com/r/$SUBREDDIT/rss` you have a image feed for a specific subreddit. I love to see images directly in my feed reader. No need to click on Reddit links and open browser.

example URL https://imgur.com/r/trashy/rss

All those feeds stopped updating two days ago 21.07.2016. Is this a temporally problem or did Imgur discontinue those feeds?

[image]

The global feed (top voted stuff) still works and gets updated frequently. Hosted by [Feedburner](https://feeds.feedburner.com/ImgurGallery?format=xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those feeds were down for a week. Now working fine. I didn't find any background info about this downtime in [Imgur Blog](https://blog.imgur.com/category/eng/) under tag #Engineering. There seems to be only funny GIFs and images.